# How to support the runtime settings ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions in unit tests (Visual Studio)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, exception, task

How can I activate the runtime settings ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions in unit tests (Visual Studio 2012 unit test environment)?

I have tried to add an App.config file in the unit test project with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. The following unit test should fail because a task throws an unhandled exception. How can I achieve this?

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Test");
    });

    // Sleep is necessary so that the task can finish.
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    // GC.Collect is necessary so that the finalizer of the 
    // Task is called which throws the exception.
    GC.Collect();
}
```

The unit test above is just a simplified sample to reproduce the issue I have. These unhandled exceptions might be called inside an external library and there is no way to handle the exceptions myself.

Comment: You have to use Framework 4.5+ and don't forget to remove old config, so that new one (with `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` set) will be copied. Then it should works. VS2013u4.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to cause your test to fail, but the following code at least resulted in the exception information appearing in the test output:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void SetThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions()
{
    Type taskExceptionHolder = typeof(Task).Assembly
        .GetType("System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder", false);
    if (taskExceptionHolder != null)
    {
        var field = taskExceptionHolder.GetField("s_failFastOnUnobservedException",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        field.SetValue(null, true);
    }
}
```

It looks like the native code for the finalizer thread checks an additional property which cannot be set through reflection, which actually causes the process to terminate. I'm not 100% sure on this though.